# UISwipeGestureRecognizer Swipe length

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

Any idea if there is a way to get the length of a swipe gesture or the touches so that i can calculate the distance?

Comment: I think you can only get direction from UISwipeGestureRecognizer. Maybe you can get the position where the touch begin and where it ends and calculate the lengh from that.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's impossible to get a distance from a swipe gesture, because the SwipeGesture triggers the method where you could access the location exactly one time, when the gesture has ended.
Maybe you want to use a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

If it possible for you to use pan gesture you would save the starting point of the pan, and if the pan has ended calculate the distance.

```
- (void)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        startLocation = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint stopLocation = [sender locationInView:self.view];
        CGFloat dx = stopLocation.x - startLocation.x;
        CGFloat dy = stopLocation.y - startLocation.y;
        CGFloat distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy );
        NSLog(@"Distance: %f", distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: If using a UIPanGestureRecognizer, the built in method     - (CGPoint)translationInView:(UIView *)view works very well.

Comment: You'd certainly use translationInView here.  Perhaps MB could edit the answer one day, since, it's such a high-marker! Eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888276/with-uipangesturerecognizer-is-there-a-way-to-only-act-so-often-like-after-x-m Rock on...

Comment: @MatthiasBauch is this in inches?

Answer (score 16):

**In Swift**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // add your pan recognizer to your desired view
    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(panedView))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)

}

   @objc func panedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        var startLocation = CGPoint()
        //UIGestureRecognizerState has been renamed to UIGestureRecognizer.State in Swift 4
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began) {
            startLocation = sender.location(in: self.view)
        }
        else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended) {
            let stopLocation = sender.location(in: self.view)
            let dx = stopLocation.x - startLocation.x;
            let dy = stopLocation.y - startLocation.y;
            let distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy );
            NSLog("Distance: %f", distance);

        if distance > 400 {
            //do what you want to do
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps all you Swift pioneers

Comment: for lazy people you should also declare `var startLocation = CGPoint()` in your class

Comment: agreed @RaduUrsache, there is no way to store the start location in this solution above.

Answer (score 4):

```
func swipeAction(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let transition = sqrt(pow(gesture.translation(in: view).x, 2)
                     + pow(gesture.translation(in: view).y, 2))
}
```

Comment: Please note: code only answers are discouraged. Please add a bit of explanation.

Comment: Its the equation to calculate distance between two points.  https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html

Answer (score 3):

For those of us using Xamarin:

```
void panGesture(UIPanGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer) {
    if (gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
        startLocation = gestureRecognizer.TranslationInView (view)
    } else if (gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        PointF stopLocation = gestureRecognizer.TranslationInView (view);
        float dX = stopLocation.X - startLocation.X;
        float dY = stopLocation.Y - startLocation.Y;
        float distance = Math.Sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Distance: {0}", distance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only do it a standard way: remember the touch point of touchBegin and compare the point from touchEnd.

Answer (score 0):

I have an implementation similar to the answer in swift that discriminates between a drag and a swipe calculating the distance relative to the container and the speed of the swipe.

```
@objc private func handleSwipe(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.state == .began) {
        self.swipeStart.location = sender.location(in: self)
        self.swipeStart.time = Date()
    }
    else if (sender.state == .ended) {
        let swipeStopLocation : CGPoint = sender.location(in: self)
        let dx : CGFloat = swipeStopLocation.x - swipeStart.location.x
        let dy : CGFloat = swipeStopLocation.y - swipeStart.location.y
        let distance : CGFloat = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy );
        let speed : CGFloat = distance / CGFloat(Date().timeIntervalSince(self.swipeStart.time))
        let portraitWidth = min(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
        print("Distance: \(distance), speed: \(speed), dy: \(dy), dx: \(dx), portraitWidth: \(portraitWidth), c1: \(distance >  portraitWidth * 0.4), c2: \(abs(dy) < abs(dx) * 0.25), c3: \(speed > portraitWidth * 3.0) ")
        if distance >  portraitWidth * 0.4 && abs(dy) < abs(dx) * 0.25 && speed > portraitWidth * 3.0 {
            if dx > 0 {
                delegate?.previousAssetPressed(self)
            }else{
                delegate?.nextAssetPressed(self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```