# UIView Receive Touch And Slide Action

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios4, action, transition

I am a newbee in iOS development; and i want to develop a simple application.

In my application there is a view that is a member of xib. I want to receive user's touch and slide actions on my view to run some sliding animations.

I found some codes about this animation but i couldn't find how can i receive sliding action in UIView.

At least, i wanna explain why i used view. This view will contains two or more labes. So i couldn't be sure to choose Rect Button or UIView.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html). There are tonnes of resources and examples online. For example, [here's](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/4/ipad-gestures.html) an example on how to use swipe (slide) gesture recognizers.

Comment: Very thanks for your answer. It is what i need. But i have one more question, how can i get gesture length? I can get where the gesture starts, but i couldn't find how can i get length of gesture.

Comment: Don't think you can do that with swipes. Another user asked the same question and someone recommended him to use pan gestures instead. Check it out here  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828833/uiswipegesturerecognizer-swipe-length