# On iOS, to find the ending swipe location, we need to use UIPanGestureRecognizer, so why not use touchesEnded?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

It is said that a Swipe Gesture `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` cannot tell the ending location of the swipe (which is kind of strange), and that we need to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` instead, as described in this question: [UISwipeGestureRecognizer Swipe length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828833/uiswipegesturerecognizer-swipe-length)

But using that method, isn't it the same if `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` is used instead?  Is there a reason or advantage to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either ... depends on your choice. It actually depends on your requirement and what you really want to do. If you want to use `UITouch` you can go ahead .

Also in the link you provided there is the last answer "You can only do it a standard way: remember the touch point of touchBegin and compare the point from touchEnd."

So touches is a lengthier method whereas using gestures makes your code look less .

Comment: i think as in that link, the gesture is handled in one handler, while touchesBegan and touchesEnded require two handlers... but the code inside the handlers add up to about the same in either case?  Besides, you don't need to create and add the GestureRecognizer if using touchesBegan.

Comment: I guess one advantage might be, the maximum number of touches can be set to 1, and the velocity can be checked if it is a Pan, so that a slow dragging isn't considered to be a quick swipe.

Comment: Yeah you can do that eventually, but anyways slow dragging would be considered as Pan rite not swipe ?

Comment: yeah, maybe a slow dragging shouldn't be considered to be a swipe because swipe is usually a quick action